# VHDL/FPGA Tacho Pulse Counter

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

I am attempting to implement a tachometer interface that will accept digital pulses as an input. I simply count clk rising edges (50Mhz) between each rising edge of the tacho pulses (1Mhz). I have found examples on the web that achieve what I need to do, but in an attempt to not make the same mistakes in the future I would like to understand why this solution doesn't work.

When I say doesn't work I mean post-synthesis functional simulation doesn't produce the results I would expect. The behavioral simulation does output the values I was expecting.

In summary, synthesis appears to be ignoring my attempt to reset a variable to 0 (see comment 'this does not appear to execute' below). The tacho_count output increments without resetting. See simulation plots below.

```
entity tacho_interface is
    Generic ( 
        FREQ_DIVISOR : integer := 6;
        MIN_RPM : integer := 200
    );
    Port ( 
        enable : in STD_LOGIC;
        clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        pump_tacho : in STD_LOGIC;
        tacho_count : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
        error: out STD_LOGIC := '0'
    );
end tacho_interface;

architecture Behavioral of tacho_interface is
begin

process
variable last_tacho : std_logic := '1';
variable tracking_cntr : integer := 0;
begin
    if (clk'event and clk = '1') then
        if (pump_tacho = '1' and pump_tacho /= last_tacho) then
            tacho_count <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(tracking_cntr * FREQ_DIVISOR, tacho_count'length));
            wait for 0ns;                
            tracking_cntr := 0; --this does not execute
        end if;
        last_tacho := pump_tacho;
        tracking_cntr := tracking_cntr + 1;
    end if;
    wait on clk;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

**Post-Synthesis Simulation illustrating problem 
(accumulation without reset to 0)**

[image]

**Behavioral Simulation illustrating what I expected**

[image]

Comment: is 'wait for 0nS' synthesisable?

Comment: Use signals, not variables. Amongst other reasons, results of simulation and synthesis here will differ with variables but wouldn't with signals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delay statements are not synthesizable. Have a look at this:

https://www.nandland.com/articles/synthesizable-vs-non-synthesizable-code-fpga-asic.html

Comment: Good to know. I assumed the synthesis tool would have thrown an error. I guess that would be too convenient.

Comment: They should, but again, when have we ever gotten an error message we deserve?